# Broadcast receiver for clipboard activity

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, clipboard, background-service

Even when the application is not running, I want to grab the content whenever something is copied.

For example, if the user copies something then, the application will receive a broadcast and start a service (calling an API, in my case). ALL IN THE BACKGROUND. I tried setting a broadcast receiver for `USER_PRESENT` and managing the clipboard from there, but in vain.

Answer (score 1):

[As of Android 10, this is not possible](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#clipboard-data) unless your app currently has input focus (that is, not in the background) or is the user's currently selected keyboard app.

Because this is a privacy feature, there is, for better or worse, no way around it other than integrating the feature you want to build into a keyboard app.

Comment: Yep. I came around that too. Okay. Now leaving this fact, I am concentrating on before versions, how could it be done now..